# QGIS3 copying field values from virtual to static field in Python

Tags: qgis, python, virtual-field, macro

I want to store values from a virtual field to a static field (the file will be used externally and I need those calculated values from the virtual field hard coded). My idea was to  write a python code snippet and add this to the Project macros `saveProject()`, so when I close QGIS, after working on the layer, the virtual field would be copied to a static field for outside use. I'm new to Python an have come so far:

```
# Import required modules
from qgis.core import edit

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my_trails_z_epsg3857')[0]
# index of target field
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName('description')

with edit(layer):
    for feat in layer.getFeatures():
        # write new_values from virtual field <CP_description> to target field
        new_value = feat['CP_description']
        layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), idx, new_value)
```

However, after running this code in the PY Console for testing, no new values are written to the target field..

Comment: Your code works when I test it. A couple of things to check: Is your `description` field the right data type? If you accidentally created an integer field, inserting strings will result in `NULL` values. Is the layer already in edit mode? If so, an assertion error will be thrown by `with edit` and the code within the block will not run.

Comment: thanks @Matt for trying the code! I'll check if there is some issues with the values maybe (data types are good)..

Comment: @Matt I reckon that it has to do with some buggy behavior due to the feature values, which is very long text (>255 chars), with emojis and some html tags.. The File I'm working on is a geojson file. The field type/length of the target field is string/1000..

Comment: If you set the field length to 0 then it will be unlimited, not sure if that will fix it, but worth a try.

Comment: @Matt i had field length set to 0, too.. But it keeps behaving buggy (not writing any values, all NULLs). I don't get it.